# Save pictures into Gallery (internal)

Tags: android, android-gallery, android-storage

I need to save picture to a Gallery, just to a normal place where the Photos are going. On SO I've found that Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM) is internal, no matter that it says ExternalStorage.
But mkdirs always return me false.

```
 String mediaStorage  =
                Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM).getAbsolutePath() + "/Camera";
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(mediaStorage);
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.activity, "failed to create directory", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Is there an easy way to save pics to an internal Gallery directory?

In case, my manifest has :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32635704/android-permission-doesnt-work-even-if-i-have-declared-it

Comment: doesn't it return false because the directory already exists?

Comment: @zarcel but it checks first for it

Comment: @CommonsWare no, I'm testing it on Android 4.3

Comment: If you use `adb shell` to look, is the directory created?